# Stacked bar graph with fill ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've read through the ggplot2 docs website and other question but I couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to visualize some data for varying age groups. I have sort of managed to do it but it does not look like I would intend it to.

Here is the code for my plot

```
p <- ggplot(suggestion, aes(interaction(Age,variable), value, color = Age, fill = factor(variable), group = Age))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facet_grid(.~Age)![The facetting separates the age variables][1]
```

My ultimate goal is to created a stack bar graph, which is why I used the fill, but it does not put the TDX values in its corresponding Age group and Year. (Sometimes TDX values == DX values, but I want to visualize when they don't)
[image: Trying to fill TDX values into DX values]

Here's the `dput(suggestion)`

```
    structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L), .Label = c("0-2", "3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", 
"65+", "UNSP", "(all)"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Year.10.DX", "Year.11.DX", 
"Year.12.DX", "Year.13.DX", "Year.10.TDX", "Year.11.TDX", "Year.12.TDX", 
"Year.13.TDX"), class = "factor"), value = c(26.8648932910636, 
30.487741796656, 31.9938838749782, 62.8189679326958, 72.8480838120064, 
69.3044125928752, 36.9789457527416, 21.808001825378, 24.1073451428435, 
40.3305134762935, 70.4486116545885, 68.8342676191755, 63.9227718107745, 
34.6086468618636, 8.84033719571875, 13.2807072303835, 28.4781516422802, 
55.139497471546, 59.7230544500003, 67.9448927372699, 37.7293286937066, 
6.9507024051526, 17.4393054963572, 33.1485743479821, 61.198647580693, 
58.6845873573852, 48.0073013177248, 28.4455801248562, 26.8648932910636, 
19.8044453272475, 23.0189084635948, 53.7037832071889, 60.6516550126422, 
58.1573725886767, 27.0791868812255, 21.808001825378, 19.8146296425633, 
35.0587750051557, 62.3308555053346, 59.3299998610862, 56.5341245769817, 
27.7229319271878, 8.84033719571875, 13.2807072303835, 22.4081606349585, 
48.0252683906252, 52.7560684009579, 65.2890977685045, 32.4142337849399, 
6.9507024051526, 15.2833655677215, 24.5268503180754, 52.536784326675, 
51.4100599515986, 40.9609231655724, 18.1306673637441)), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), .Names = c("Age", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you can create stacked barplots with `geom_bar(position = 'fill')` but I don't know why you would want that after you have done all the stratifying/faceting here--you'd end up with each bar one color and pretty meaningless

Comment: Hey @rawr thanks for your comment. Yeah I think you're right about position = "fill" not being super helpful

I'm trying to fill the values because its helps visualize if you get diagnosed with a disease - DX and of those # of DX how may get treated - TDX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you need but perhaps this.

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=variable,y=value,fill=Age)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')     
+facet_wrap(~Age)
```

[image]

If you want to visualize separately the TDX and the DX entries, we'll need to change the dataframe a bit.

```
> head(a)
Age   variable    value
1   0-2 Year.10.DX 26.86489
2   3-9 Year.10.DX 30.48774
3 10-19 Year.10.DX 31.99388
4 20-39 Year.10.DX 62.81897
5 40-59 Year.10.DX 72.84808
6 60-64 Year.10.DX 69.30441
```

The column of interest `variable` is a combination of year and of TDX/DX value. We'll use the `tidyr` package to separate this into two columns.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tidy_a<- a %>% separate(variable, into = c( 'nothing',"year",'label'), sep = "\\.")
```

This actually splits the `levels` of column `variable` into three components, since we split on `.` and the character `.` appears twice in each entry.

```
> head(tidy_a)
Age nothing year label    value
1   0-2    Year   10    DX 26.86489
2   3-9    Year   10    DX 30.48774
3 10-19    Year   10    DX 31.99388
4 20-39    Year   10    DX 62.81897
5 40-59    Year   10    DX 72.84808
6 60-64    Year   10    DX 69.30441
```

So the column `nothing` is rather useless, just a necessary result of using `separate` and separating on `.`.  Now this will allow us to visualize TDX/DX separately.

```
ggplot(tidy_a,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=label)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_wrap(~Age)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @keegan, you're second solution looks wonderful. Do you know how we could modify it so that the the TDX values fill in the corresponding DX values?

"I'm trying to fill the values because its helps visualize if you get diagnosed with a disease - DX and of those # of DX how many get treated - TDX"

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what you mean here. I don't see anything called TDX, only DX. See levels(a$variable) returns just 
     "Year.10.DX" "Year.11.DX" "Year.12.DX" "Year.13.DX"

Comment: i apparently put the wrong the dput, hopefully you can see what I mean now

Comment: Hey there @keegan, you're solution and u/hadley both seem to be telling me that I need to learn how to tidy my data. One modification that I'm making to your code is that `geom_bar(stat='identity', position = "dodge")` Makes it easier to assess how the values are changing. :) 

[Your help is appreciated](https://imgur.com/JWdyTQk)